# Compile Bootstrap CSS like TailwindCSS to have only the used classes CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, tailwind-css

We have some projects that use Bootstrap and we have been including the whole Bootstrap library.   This has been adding a lot of extra CSS that we don't actually use to the page load.   We've also started using TailwindCSS on projects and one of the features we really like about it is that it will compile only the CSS that we have used.

Is it possible to configure Bootstrap/Webpack(or something like that) to scan the markup like Tailwind can and compile only what we need and not include the whole Bootstrap CSS library?

Comment: Have you tried using UnCSS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncss)?

Comment: I have checked that out but ideally i don't want to have a generate the page first.  i would prefer to have the process scan the files in the project and update as needed.

Comment: You could try [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/). It removes the seemingly unused CSS.